# Where can I to write my logic in APIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In the `CreateAPIView` I can override the `create` method to add my logic:

```
class OpenstackAccountCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    """
    create openstack account
    """
    serializer_class = OpenstackAccountCreateSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # put my logic here
        ......
```

But if I have a APIView, where can I to write my logic?

```
class OpenstackAccountLoginAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = OpenstackAccountLoginSerializer
    # where can I put my login logic?
```

My OpenstackAccountLoginSerializer in serializers.py:

```
class OpenstackAccountLoginSerializer(Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overide the method of the verb you want. Probably to create an account you'll want POST. Like this:

```
class OpenstackAccountLoginAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = OpenstackAccountLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # Logic goes here, defining resp with whatever you want to respond.
        return Response(resp)
```

Than you can call it with the POST verb, same as when using `create` with `CreateAPIView` as in the documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview).

Answer (score 0):

```
class OpenstackAccountLoginAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = OpenstackAccountLoginSerializer
    def get(self, request):
        """
        Return a list of all users.
        """
    def post(self, request):
        """
        Create users.
        """
```